# super and mix-in class: how exactly is the search order altered?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I'm reading this article:
https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

He's trying to explain the purpose of a '*mix-in class*' and he says

> We did not alter the source code for `LoggingDict`. Instead we built a
>   subclass whose only logic is to compose two existing classes and
>   control **their search order.**

```
class LoggingOD(LoggingDict, collections.OrderedDict):
    pass
```

My question is this: in the above article context, is he talking about the  `LoggingDict`'s search order that is being manipulated? Or he is talking about manipulating the `LoggingOD` search order?

He says very clearly *"not alter the source code for `LoggingDict`"* so clearly he means that somehow, magically - the search order for `super().__setitem__` in

```
class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        logging.info('Settingto %r' % (key, value))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

is being altered/influenced, but how? Could someone clarify what exactly is going on here? Far as I can make of it, the tree looks like this:
[image: super_search]

Comment: Did you read the preceding paragraph? *"the important result is that `OrderedDict` was inserted after `LoggingDict` and before `dict`! This means that the `super()` call in `LoggingDict.__setitem__` now dispatches the key/value update to `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`."* The method resolution order (MRO) flattens the diagram you have drawn, as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: i did read that para - in fact it's underlined in yellow. My point is: LoggingDict has NOT been altered in any way at all - the src hasn't been changed. So LoggingDict DOES NOT inherit LoggingOD, INSTEAD it's the other-way around. So how the heck is the fact that LoggingOD deriving from LoggingDict, altering the LoggingDict.__mro__ ???? It should alter the LoggingOD.__mro__

Comment: therefore any instance of LoggingOD will use the LoggingOD.__mro__ and have it's lookup sent to collections.OrderedDict

Comment: isn't inheritance a one way street?

Comment: *"LoggingDict has NOT been altered in any way"* - correct. *"LoggingDict DOES NOT inherit LoggingOD, INSTEAD it's the other-way around"* - correct, and nothing has implied otherwise. *"how the heck is the fact that LoggingOD deriving from LoggingDict, altering the LoggingDict.__mro__"* - it doesn't, as you could see by printing it before and after defining `LoggingOD`. *"It should alter the LoggingOD.__mro__"* - not "alter" so much "create", but yes. *"any instance of LoggingOD will use the LoggingOD.__mro__ and have it's lookup sent to collections.OrderedDict"* - also yes.

Comment: Note it says *"control"* the search order - not *"alter"*. The existence of `LoggingOD` doesn't change the classes it inherits from. *"isn't inheritance a one way street?"* - yes, and it's not clear how you think this is claiming otherwise.

Comment: but if that is the case, a lookup on an instance attribute of LoggingDict cannot take the path marked 1 (that's a one-way street) LoggingDict is the PARENT class of LoggingOD. Searches don't propagate down the tree

Comment: Please read the duplicate and take some time to absorb it. Also see https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/. The inheritance tree is not the same as the resulting flattened MRO.